# How to scrape data from an interactive chart using python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the date and total value data from the "Value History" chart on the following link when the chart is set to 1Y:
https://csgoskins.gg/markets/csgofloat

I've tried to look and see if the data on the site is stored in a json file, but it does not seem like it.

I found this looking at the javascript code of the site, which makes me think the data is stored within a variable called t, but I haven't been able to find it:

```
series: [{
                        name: "Total Value",
                        type: "line",
                        showInNavigator: !0,
                        color: "#60a5fa",
                        marker: {
                            lineColor: "#60a5fa"
                        },
                        data: t.map((function(t) {
                            return [Date.parse(t.day), t.sales_value]
                        }
```

Which is part of a function called: `window.createMarketValueHistoryChart = function(t)`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `history` variable in the console. Something like:

```js
history.forEach(v => {console.log(v.day, v.sales_value)})
```

will print the data you need.

---

#### Getting it to pandas

If you use Chrome (but I'd assume that should work for most browsers), in the console write `history`, hit enter, right-click on the output, "Copy object". Paste it into `data.json` file and read with:

```py
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! Do you know of any way I can save the output as a json file, so that it will be easier to plot into a pandas dataframe?